# Apollo 2.0 Client apollo-link-state Cache isAuthenticated

Tags: javascript, redux, apollo, apollo-client

Apollo 2.0 allows user to manage the application global state via apollo-link-state by using the browser's cache. I know it is a common pattern in Redux to have a variable `isAuthenticated` in the global store to restrict access (and to my understanding this is not saved in the cache).

My question is: is it dangerous to have a state `isAuthenticated` saved in the cache using apollo-link-state? Can the user not simply modify the state of `isAuthenticated` and be granted access to the site? Should I therefore avoid using `isAuthenticated` as a global variable in Apollo Client?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you save `isAuthenticated` as long as you check on the backend if the user really is authenticated if he/she requests anything. Client side cannot be trusted exactly because the user can control anything if they try hard enough. So if you verify every request from the client, with a token for example, it really doesn't matter if they manually changed a variable, they simple won't get any restricted content. Unless they really have access to valid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As @tal-z said: Never trust the client